# Crontab not executing

Tags: cron

I have a shell script and a python script I would like to have executed every two minutes. One is a curl request, another one analyses its content.

This is what is in my crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * $HOME/Routes/curl.sh
*/2 * * * * $HOME/Routes/analyse.py >> $HOME/Routes/analyse.log 2>&1
```

Both files are made executable with `chmod +x`. A file "analyse.log" is being created - but there is nothing in there.

`grep CRON /var/log/syslog` show the occurence of this message, every time the files should be executed.

Jan 14 20:36:01 raspberry CRON[23217]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

What am I missing out? Wheres my mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MTA is "mail transfer agent", a program that sends email.  Cron is telling you that it wanted to send you email reporting the result of the job execution but it couldn't find a program that it could use to do that.

Cron tries to send email whenever a job writes something to its standard error stream, so presumably your `curl.sh` script complained about something going wrong.  (Your `analyse.py` folds its stderr into stdout so that shouldn't pass any messages to cron, unless something is going wrong so early that the redirection is not yet in force.)  You could try editing the `curl.sh` job to redirect stderr into a file so that you can see what it's trying to tell you:

```
*/2 * * * * $HOME/Routes/curl.sh 2>$HOME/Routes/curl-stderr.txt
```

BTW, if `analyse.py` is supposed to examine the output of `curl.sh` then it seems strange that you're telling cron to run them simultaneously.  Wouldn't it make more sense to have cron run them one one after the other as part of a single job?  Like:

```
*/2 * * * * $HOME/Routes/curl.sh ; $HOME/Routes/analyse.py >> $HOME/Routes/analyse.log 2>&1
```

One very common reason for scripts to fail is that they depend on being executed in a particular working directory or being executed with environment settings that exist in the user's terminal shell but that do not exist in the environment of a cron job.  `$PATH` is a strong candidate for being different in these two contexts. You might try running your scripts like this:

```
  cd $HOME
  env PATH="/usr/bin:/bin" SHELL=/bin/sh $HOME/Routes/curl.sh
  env PATH="/usr/bin:/bin" SHELL=/bin/sh $HOME/Routes/analyse.py
```

to check that they behave properly in cron's stripped-down environment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. your advice on the parallel processing was very helpful.

my main problem was Cron working on the wrong directory. I had some relative paths in the scripts which worked when ececuted in the shell, since I was in the right directort. Cron again seems to have a different working directory which caused troubles.

thanks again!